# Using environmental variables with mac / python

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, environment-variables

I don't understand what is the problem with my environmental variables which I try to use with my python script...

What I have done:

Make a new .bash_profile file to the location ~ with following code:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Write this into the opened file:

```
export test="it works"
```

then in my python script:

```
import os

test = os.environ.get('test')
print(test)
```

Prints:

```
None
```

According to instructions, it should be fine with this... It would be necessary to hide my API keys with this asap.

EDIT: actually now when I tried, it works when I execute the python script from terminal, but doesn't work when I execute the script from Pycharm editor... Any ideas?

Comment: Try running `source ~/.bash_profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile` in Terminal before executing your Python script.

Comment: actually now when I tried, it works when I execute the python script from terminal, but doesn't work when I execute the script from Pycharm editor... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the opened file is saved. If saved, then to reload .bash_profile from the command line

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

The problem was that PYCHARM uses different environmental variables, and you can add those in:

> edit configurations
>
> select wanted project
>
> --> now you can see the 'Environmental variable' definition part.